# How to randomly get min value from Array?

Tags: php, arrays, random, minimum

I have an array with multiple similar minimum value.
May I know how to randomly get one of the minimum value?

Here is my sample code:-

```
$aryNo = array(
                    0 => 34, 1 => 34, 2 => 51, 3 => 12, 4 => 12,
                    5 => 12, 6 => 56, 7 => 876, 8 => 453, 9 => 43,
                    10 => 12
);
$b = array_keys($aryNo, min($aryNo));  //Here only can get 1 value.
$intNo = $b[0];
```

May I know how to get min value list (3 => 12, 4 => 12,5 => 12,10 => 12) and randomly pick one of them so that I can set in $intNo?

Comment: And what's the point of selecting subarray if you need one value?

Comment: @u_mulder, I need to select only 1 of the number from min value list. $aryNo might be got only 1 min value or multiple min value. Any idea?

Comment: `array_rand` or `shuffle`

Comment: Hi u_mulder, thanks for your suggestion. But how can I apply array_rand / shuffle for both (key and value) together in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$aryNo = array(
    0 => 34, 1 => 34, 2 => 51, 3 => 12, 4 => 12,
    5 => 12, 6 => 56, 7 => 876, 8 => 453, 9 => 43,
    10 => 12
);
$b = array_keys($aryNo, min($aryNo));  //Here only can get 1 value.

// Taking a random KEY from $b
$key = array_rand($b);

// Taking a KEY from $aryNo which is under `$key`
echo $b[$key];

// Taking a VALUE from `$aryNo` which is under `$b[$key]`
echo $aryNo[$b[$key]];
```

[The fiddle](https://3v4l.org/qljOY).

Comment: Thanks u_mulder for your answer, I found if I using  shuffle();  also work for my case. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$aryNo = [34,34,34,51,12,12,12,56,876,453,43,12];

foreach($aryNo as $a) {
 $finalArray[$a][] = $a;   
}

print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray,true)."</pre>");
$minKey = min(array_keys($finalArray));
print("<pre>".print_r($finalArray[$minKey],true)."</pre>");
$randIndex = array_rand($finalArray[$minKey]);
print_r("Key: ".$randIndex.", ".$finalArray[$minKey][$randIndex]);
```

First print prints:

```
Array
(
    [34] => Array
        (
            [0] => 34
            [1] => 34
            [2] => 34
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 12
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 12
            [3] => 12
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [0] => 56
        )

    [876] => Array
        (
            [0] => 876
        )

    [453] => Array
        (
            [0] => 453
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [0] => 43
        )

)
```

Than you select min key, and that prints this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 12
)
```

At the end you pick random key from this array and print the value:

```
Key: 2, Value: 12
```

Comment: Hi @JureW, thanks for your answer. But my case is consider multidimensional array. Like above example, I need to get the key from list is 3 or 4 or 5 or 10 (due to all of them have max value 12) but not [0] / [1] / [2] / [3]. May I know how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
`<?php
    $sortArr = array();
    $aryNo = array(0 => 34, 1 => 34, 2 => 51, 3 => 12, 4 => 12,5 => 
    12, 6 => 56, 7 => 876, 8 => 453, 9 => 43,10 => 12);
    asort($aryNo);
$aryNo = array_values($aryNo);
print_r($aryNo);
echo $aryNo[0];
?>`
```

Comment: Hi V77, my case if how to get multiple key from max value array. From your example, only will return max value. Therefore, your answer is not suite to my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I using shuffle(); also work for me.
Here is my example:-

```
$aryNo = array(
                    0 => 34, 1 => 34, 2 => 51, 3 => 12, 4 => 12,
                    5 => 12, 6 => 56, 7 => 876, 8 => 453, 9 => 43,
                    10 => 12
);
 $aryNo2 = array_keys($aryNo, min($aryNo));
                shuffle($aryNo2); //
                $intWinNo = $aryNo2[0];
```

Thanks @u_mulder suggestion & answer.